# Is it possible to summarize or group every row with a specific column value? - python

Tags: python, pandas, sum

[Picture of my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8BI4.png)

Is it possible to summarize or group every country's info to something like a 'total info' `row`

This `df` is fluent, it will change each month and having a "quick access" view of how it looks will be very beneficial.

Take the picture as example: I would like to have Albania's (every county's) info in row so something like this

`**ORIGINATING COUNTRY Calls Made  Actual Qty  Billable Qty.   Cost (€)**`

`Albania               10            190           600             7`

`Zambia                total           total           total`

`and                   total           total           total`

`every                 total           total           total`

`other                 total           total           total`

`country in my df      total           total           total`

I've tried `groupby()` and `sum()` but can figure it out.

Comment: Hi. You can simply add the countries and the fields you need in a dictionary (something like : {country: "Albania", calls: n, actualQty: n, billableQty: n, cost: n}) (you can create the dicts by turning a copy of df['COUNTRY'] into a set and then loop over the set to create the dicts). 
Then you can loop over your dataframe to sum under the condition that the country is the same.

Comment: Hey, it now worked with ``df.groupby('ORIGINATING COUNTRY').sum()`` dont know why it worked now and not before..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        ['Albania', 1, 10, 100, 0.1],
        ['Albania', 2, 20, 200, 0.2],
        ['Zambia', 3, 30, 300, 0.3],
        ['Zambia', 4, 40, 400, 0.4],
        [None, 5, 50, 500, 0.5],
        [None, 6, 60, 600, 0.6],
    ],
    columns=[
        'ORIGINATING COUNTRY',
        'Calls Made',
        'Actual Qty. (s)',
        'Billable Qty. (s)',
        'Cost (€)',
    ],
)

df['ORIGINATING COUNTRY'].replace({None: 'Unknown'}, inplace=True)

df.groupby('ORIGINATING COUNTRY', as_index=False).sum()
```

Output:

```
  ORIGINATING COUNTRY  Calls Made  Actual Qty. (s)  Billable Qty. (s)  Cost (€)
0             Albania           3               30                300       0.3
1             Unknown          11              110               1100       1.1
2              Zambia           7               70                700       0.7
```

Comment: Thank you @Filip, this works. It does as you see in your output change the location of ``ORIGINATING COUTNRY`` (it is no longer in the same spot as the other titles) is there a way to prevent this? ``data.loc[data['ORIGINATING COUNTRY'] == 'Botswana']`` for example does not work because the column isn't found ``KeyError: 'ORIGINATING COUNTRY'``

Comment: @Monsson You can use the keyword `as_index=False`. I adjusted my answer accordingly.